# How to change the order of divs in a 2x2 grid

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to make my 2x2 grid of divs take on a different order. I am trying to use flexbox for this.

I have tried to simplify my situation in a Codepen and I come quite far, yet I cannot perform the last step.

[image]

I want to swap number 2 and 3 so the order is goes from top right to top left.

Here is the code I use for the above output:

```css
.container {
  height: 600px;
  width: 800px;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container2 {
  // flex-direction: column-reverse <-- this does not work
}

.square {
  font-size: 84px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container1">
    <div class="square">
      0
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container2">
    <div class="square">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know a simple addition or, if necessary, a bigger change that will make this work?

Thanks in advance for your responses!

EDIT: Perhaps it is important to say that there will not always be 4 squares. 4 will be the maximum but there may also be 1, 2 or 3 squares.

Comment: Is there gone be more elements or just always this 4?

Comment: @Dejan.S It will be a maximum of 4. There can be 1, 2 or 3 elements too

Comment: why you are not using order property?

Comment: @sundeepsharma I tried that following the answers I got below, but found out it doesn't really work nicely with a dynamic amount of squares. If you have a vast amount that works greatly but my amount will differ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage this by manipulating the size of the overall container and adjusting the various flex-directions of each sub-container.

```css
.container {
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.container2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.square {
  font-size: 42px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container1">
    <div class="square">
      0
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container2">
    <div class="square">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="container1">
    <div class="square">
      0
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container2">
    <div class="square">
      2
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works greatly! It also works without the align flex-end and the inline-flex btw :)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use a simple approach?

```
#flex { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
#a { order: 2; }
#b { order: 1; }
#c { order: 3; }

<div id="flex">
   <div id="a">A</div>
   <div id="b">B</div>
   <div id="c">C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works with a vast amount of elements, but not with different amounts. I forgot to add, but the number of elements will differ with a maximum of 4.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the order of any flex child using `order`

check this to know more about flex in css
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.container {
  height: 600px;
  width: 800px;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container1,.container2 {
display:flex;
   flex-direction: column;
 justify-content:flex-end;
}

.square {
  font-size: 84px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

.order-1{
order:1;
}

.order-2{
order:2
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container1">
    <div class="square">
      0
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container2">
    <div class="square order-2">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="square order-1">
      3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works with 4 elements, but not with 3 for example. I forgot to add, but the number of elements will differ with a maximum of 4.